# Do i need a scheduler to create daily log files with the hslogger library of Haskell?

Tags: haskell, logging, hslogger

First of all, this is my first experience ever with logs; and i don't really know what a scheduler is, only heard about them.

Now, as a first approach, i want to make a file with only important logs (`WARNING` or above), and daily files (like `2017-7-20.log`) for all possible logged messages that day.

This is my code atm:

```
module Utilities.Loggers where


import System.Log.Logger
-- import System.Log.Handler.Syslog   (TODO: remote logs)
import System.Log.Handler.Simple
import System.Log.Handler (LogHandler, setFormatter)
import System.Log.Formatter
import Data.Time
import GHC.IO.Handle (Handle)


--------------------------------------------

importantLogsPath :: FilePath
importantLogsPath = "app/logs/prioritary.log"

logsFolder :: FilePath
logsFolder = "app/logs/allLogs/"


defaultFormat :: LogFormatter a
defaultFormat = simpleLogFormatter "[$utcTime : $tid : $loggername : $prio] $msg"

applyFormat :: LogHandler a => a -> a
applyFormat h = setFormatter h defaultFormat
--------------------------------------------


prioritaryHandler :: IO (GenericHandler Handle)
prioritaryHandler = applyFormat <$> prioritaryHandler'
    where
        prioritaryHandler' = fileHandler importantLogsPath WARNING


todaysHandler :: UTCTime ->  IO (GenericHandler Handle)
todaysHandler = (applyFormat <$>) . todaysHandler'
    where
        todaysHandler' time = fileHandler (mkPath time) DEBUG
        mkPath time = logsFolder ++ show (utctDay time) ++ ".log"


--------------------------------------------


initLogger :: IO ()
initLogger = do
    h1 <- prioritaryHandler
    timeNow <- getCurrentTime
    h2 <- todaysHandler timeNow
    updateGlobalLogger "MyApp" (setHandlers [h2,h1])
```

If i understood correctly, each handle "listens" for possible messages  that are above its priority level (daily handles have the DEBUG priority, the lowest possible, so they should catch every message)

So i need something that everyday at 00:00 utctime removes the handle for the passing day and adds the handle for the new day, right?

Also i'm a bit puzzled with the naming issues for loggers/messages, but that's just me (althout any insight will be welcome)

---

Edit: it's a web server

Comment: The hs-logger "Simple" option doesn't seem to provide anything to deal with log files. I prefer to just let the OS deal with how logs are stored. On a Linux system I'm using `monad-logger`, with `stderr` logging. I run my server via `systemd` and it handles everything to do with log storage.